# Make 2013 ribbon tabs appear

Tags: 2013, ribbon, ootb

Probably an obvious question but how do I make the other tabs on the 2013 ribbon appear? For example, on a Document Library making "Files" and "library" appear

Sometimes clicking on "Browse" works but it doesn't always work. Usually I have to click just below one of my views but this is difficult to describe to a new user

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You mean, you are finding difficulty in getting the ribbon tabs like `File` and `library`?

Comment: Yes, I can usually find them but the users can't

Comment: Do you have a content editor or any other web parts on the page?

Comment: No, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the solution but clicking to the right of "New Document" (yellow highlight) consistently makes the tabs appear for me. I'll ask my users if it works for them too

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to

- Site Actions
- Navigation
- Show and Hide Ribbon Setting

  *Set "Show Ribbon" and "Hide Ribbon" commands available* to ***No***

This will keep the ribbon always visible. Give this a try

Comment: I've changed it to No but that doesn't seem to have made any difference